# How do I test the user's input to see if its words are within a specified range

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that asks the user to enter the maximum and minimum values of words they would like to be in the essay, and then enter the essay. The program checks to see if the number of words the user inputted is within the range they specified. Is there a way I can turn my code into a method? Here's my code:

**Desired output:**

---

```
Please enter the maximum: 9

Please enter the minimum: 5

enter: hello there

2

YAY!!!!!!!!! YOU'RE WTHIN THE RAAAANGE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

---

**Here's my code:**

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("\t\tPlease enter the maximum: ");
    int max = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\t\tPlease enter the minimum: ");
    int min = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("enter: ");
    String word = input.next();
    int countwords = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (word.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            countwords++;
        }
    }
    countwords++;
    System.out.println(countwords);
    if(countwords<=max && countwords >=min){
        System.out.println(
            "YAY!!!!!!!!! YOU'RE WTHIN THE RAAAANGE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It doesnt count the number of words enterd properly and my if statement isnt working

Comment: What does "properly" and "isn't working" mean in this case?

Comment: i think you need `word.charAt(i) != ' '` , seems like you just want to skip spaces during counting

Comment: I suggest to read the essay from file, no body want to write an essay on the console. After getting the amount of words you can use your general if..else logic to find whether or not the essay in within the word range and print output accordingly. https://www.google.com.np/search?q=java+how+to+find+number+of+words+in+a+file&oq=java+how+to+find+number+of+words+in+a+file&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.13306j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak when i enter the essay it just outputs '1' and exits the program

Comment: I think counting the words by splitting the string on whitespace and taking the `length` property of the resulting array would be simpler. Also your desired output seems wrong, as you specify a minimum of 5 and only provide 2 words => it should not print out in that case

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 issues in your program:

1. You get your input text with `next()` instead of `nextLine()` such that you only get one word instead of the whole line.
2. The way you count the words is not correct as you only count the spaces, you should use something like `word.split("\\s+").length` instead which slips the content of `word` using a sequence of whitespace characters as separator then get the length to get the total amount of resulting words.

So simply change this:

```
...
System.out.print("enter: ");
String word = input.nextLine();
int countwords = word.split("\\s+").length;
```

**NB:** `hello there` contains `2` words and `2` is not between `5` and `9` so you won't get the success message with those inputs, try instead with `1` and `5` for example.

Answer (score 2):

we keep the user input in the main.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the maximum: ");
    int max = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter the minimum: ");
    int min = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine(); 
    System.out.print("enter: ");
    String word = input.nextLine();
    if(isInRange(min,max,word)){
        System.out.println(
                "YAY!!!!!!!!! YOU'RE WTHIN THE RAAAANGE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
            );
    }
```

now we move the calculation towards a method like this:

```
static boolean isInRange(int min, int max, String words) {
    int length = words.split("\\W+").length;
    if (length <= max && length >= min) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

you will get the desired output, if the amount of words is within the range. the `input.readLine();` consumes leftovers from `nextInt()`

Comment: Any reason you are storing the array instead of just the value of `length`?

Comment: It could be better to use a regex for any whitespace : ```words.split("\\s+");```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to save the return value in a cryptic boolean variable. Just return where you set `b`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [String's split method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) with a space-regex (like "\s+" or similar) to handle the word separation.

Before you split the string, you should use the [trim method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim(java.lang.String)) to be sure that there's no space before or after the string to prevent wrong splits.

And like XtremeBaumer already posted, it's nice to wrap it into a method. But I'd make a method like that then:

```
public static boolean inRange(int min, int max, String str) {
    return min <= split.trim().split("\\s+").length <= max;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        wordCountCheck();
    }

    public static void wordCountCheck() {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\t\tPlease enter the maximum: ");
        int max = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\t\tPlease enter the minimum: ");
        int min = input.nextInt();

        input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("enter: ");
        String word = input.nextLine();
        String[] wordArray = word.trim().split("\\s+");
        int countwords = wordArray.length;

        System.out.println(countwords);
        if(countwords<=max && countwords >=min){
            System.out.println(
                "YAY!!!!!!!!! YOU'RE WTHIN THE RAAAANGE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
            );
        } else {
            System.out.println(
                    "OOPS!!!!!!!!! YOU'RE NOT WTHIN THE RAAAANGE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
                );
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("\t\tPlease enter the maximum: ");
    int max = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\t\tPlease enter the minimum: ");
    int min = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("enter: ");
    Scanner lineInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = lineInput.nextLine();
    String[] lengthword = word.split("\\s+");
    int countwords = lengthword.length;
    if (countwords <= max && countwords >= min) {
        System.out
                .println("YAY!!!!!!!!! YOU'RE WTHIN THE RAAAANGE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    } else {
        System.out
                .println("Ohh!!!!!!!!! YOU'RE Not in RAAAANGE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: i laughed so hard at ur else statement thank you so much cheers

Comment: I was just wondering, why did you create a new scanner for the word input? And what do the "[]" mean after String? What does "\\s+" mean also?

Comment: \\s+ is regular expression for checking space.

Comment: Oh okay, what's the expression for checking commas or other punctuation marks?

Answer (score 1):

first finish the last line by calling ".nextLine()".

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\t\tPlease enter the maximum: ");
        int max = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\t\tPlease enter the minimum: ");
        int min = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("enter: ");
        input.nextLine();//finish the last line first
        String word = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print(word);
        int countwords = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (word.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                countwords++;
            }
        }
        countwords++;
        System.out.println(countwords);
        if(countwords<=max && countwords >=min){
            System.out.println(
                "YAY!!!!!!!!! YOU'RE WTHIN THE RAAAANGE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
            );
        }
    }
}
```